# Fat Free Framework URL Error

Tags: php, url, fat-free-framework

I'm getting a problem. I'm using Ubuntu and all my files are located in `/var/www`. It contains the following folder:

```
fatfree:contains the fat free framwork
F3Apps: contains index.php, .htaccess(contents shown below)
```

The content of the index.php is

```
<?php
require '../fatfree/lib/base.php';
F3::route('GET /',function()
{
    echo "root  entered";   
});

F3::route('GET /about',function()
{
    echo "about  entered";  
});

F3::run();
?>
```

When I'm setting the URL as http://127.0.0.1/F3Apps/, it is ok, i.e. it is echoing

```
root  entered
```

However when I'm setting the URL as http://127.0.0.1/F3Apps/about, I'm getting the following:
[image]

The .htaccess contents is shown below(The .htaccess is in the file F3Apps):

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /F3Apps
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]

# Disable ETags
<IfModule mod_header.c>
    Header Unset ETag
    FileETag none
</IfModule>

# Default expires header if none specified (stay in browser cache for 7 days)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A604800
</IfModule>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

Comment: There's something called "fat free framework"? LOL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your .htaccess, problem is there. Or post it's content for us :)